# How to get only image in PHP tab

Tags: php, image

How can i get only images (jpg, png) in php? Because it return my .DS_Store file. I suppose i have to change the "foreach"?

```
<?php
    $tabFich = array();
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator("img/travaux/renovation/mini/");
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
            $tabFich[ $fileinfo->getCTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        }
    }
    ksort( $tabFich);
    $firstFichier = reset( $tabFich );
    $dernierFichier = end( $tabFich );
?>

        <img src="img/travaux/renovation/mini/<?php echo $dernierFichier; ?>"/>
        <img class="second" src="img/travaux/renovation/mini/<?php echo $firstFichier; ?>"/>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Rénovation de villas</p>            
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items contain a [`DirectoryIterator::getExtension()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getextension.php) method which provides the extension of the current item in the iterator.

You can also skip "dot files" (`.` and `..`) by checking [`DirectoryIterator::getExtension()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php) and skip directories (as you already do) by check either [`DirectoryIterator::isFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isfile.php) or [`DirectoryIterator::isDir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdir.php).

Something like this should get you started:

```
$allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']; // add / remove extensions to your liking

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator("img/travaux/renovation/mini/");

foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile() || !in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(), $allowedExtensions, true)) continue;

    // rest of your code here
}
```

This assumes you have actually validated your images and your images have the correct extensions. Extensions can and will be liars.

Alternatively you could use [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to check whether it is an actual image (regardless of extension):

```
// add / remove types to your liking
$allowedTypes = [
    IMAGETYPE_GIF,
    IMAGETYPE_JPEG,
    IMAGETYPE_PNG,
];

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator("img/travaux/renovation/mini/");

foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile() || !in_array(@exif_imagetype($fileinfo->getPathname()), $allowedTypes, true)) continue;

    // rest of your code here
}
```